# Can I position a tooltip in the middle of the screen on mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, tooltip

Is there a way to set the position of a tooltip to the center of a screen, as opposed to relative to the text, using CSS? I am trying to make the tooltips work better on mobile.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
.tip:hover span {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 19em;    
  }
}
```

Comment: create fiddle or add some html code here?

Comment: CSS `:hover` on a mobile device?? Doesn't sound like a good idea 

Answer (score 0):

Using `:hover` is not a good idea for mobile. I've updated your CSS but your tooltips could potentially clip off the user's viewport.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
  /* As stated not sure why you'd use :hover for mobile. */
  .tip:hover span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100vh/2);
    left: calc(100vw/2);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tip">
  <span>Tooltip Content</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work? You've not provided much of your original code.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
.tip:hover span {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 19em;    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tip">
  <span>Tooltip Content</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe that if you use `left: 50%` and `top: 50%` and the parent element has `position: relative`. It will not be the center of the viewport.

Comment: Possibly not. It might be a start but it'd be good if Michelle provided a full working example.